# "No message file" problem with Oracle client

Tags: windows-7

I have installed Oracle Client 11g R2 Win64 on Windows 7 x64.
However, running tnsping (without parameters) yields the following output:

```
C:\Users\stefan.moebius>tnsping

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 01-APR-2011 17:06:17

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-03502: Message 3502 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
```

What's wrong?

I tried settings ORACLE_HOME, as that's mentioned around the net, but that didn't help. Looking at what tnsping is doing using ProcMon shows that it actually does find the file

```
C:\develop\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\mesg\nlus.msb
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue, although `nlus.msb` did exist under `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\mesg\`, there were seven more `msg` files missing. Apparently this was due to an incomplete client installation, and I had copied these file across from another machine with the same version/configuration and got rid of the issue.

```
TNSPING

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 17-FEB-2
012 10:00:23

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Message 3511 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSMessage
 3512 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSMessage 3513 n
ot found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSMessage 3509 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\mesg\tnsus.msg` (and `tnshu.msg`) disappeared, so I solved it by copying the files from another computer. (What I don't understand is that `tnsping` used to work until recently and there was no installation since then.)

Answer (score 0):

I do know the TNS-03502 message is telling you that tnsping without arguments is not legal. Do you get the same message ("message nnnn not found...") if you supply a valid TNS alias to the command?

As for the message error, the only thing I can think of is a permission issue with the user running the tnsping command and the Oracle message files. Setting ORACLE_HOME on windows boxes is unnecessary and often causes problems - that value should be set up in the registry when you installed it.

Comment: Yes, the same bogus thing happens with a complete tnsping command.

Answer (score 0):

Find ORACLE_HOME in your windows registry.
Looks like below:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\KEY_OraDb11g_home1

make sure the ORACLE_HOME is pointing to the correct home. Especially when you have installed Oracle Client/Servers more than 1x.

Works for me.